# PHP 7.3 now requires PCRE2, while Apache 2.4 HTTP Server requires PCRE

Tags: php, apache, pcre

While upgrading to PHP 7.3, I discovered that I needed to install PCRE2.   However it seems Apache HTTP Server 2.4 requires PCRE.  This seems to indicate to me that I need to have both PCRE and PCRE2 installed.  I am building a binary package of Apache 2.4.38 with PHP 7.3 for Solaris 11, and it would seem both PCRE and PCRE2 are required since PHP requires PCRE2 and Apache requires PCRE. My question is whether there is another way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence two from https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php

> By default, this extension is compiled using the bundled PCRE library. Alternatively, an external PCRE library can be used by passing in the --with-pcre-regex=DIR configuration option where DIR is the location of PCRE's include and library files.